# SSH connections keep dropping out due to inactivity

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

My SSH connections keep dropping out due to inactivity in the EC2 hosts. I have tried to put these options [1] in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` in the server and in the client, but the connections keep dropping out.

```
ServerAliveInterval 15
ServerAliveCountMax 3
```

How I make connections keep alive?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your clients SSH Config (`~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 60
```

This should keep the client from timing out.

Comment: But, if I am in the remote hosts, and don't do nothing the connection drops out. With this, the connection will not drop out?

Comment: This works for *Ubuntu*.

Comment: you didn't add the whole picture. See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn this on both client and server. Client and server use different configuration files and options. You set up correctly client side in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or rather `~/.ssh/config`:

```
ServerAliveInterval 15
ServerAliveCountMax 3
```

But server configuration is in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and should look like this:

```
ClientAliveInterval 15
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

(for example. You can adjust the numbers to your needs)